# Android Media Player Plays In The Background, But Doesn't Stop When App Killed

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, media-player

I'm new to Android, so I have a problem. In Android I want to play background music as soon as my music player starts and have it continue even if the activity changes from one to another. I've tried this code:

```
MediaPlayer music = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.bgscore);
music.start();
```

However, the sound should stop when user closes the app, and it doesn't. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use a service to play your music. check this link has a sample to download https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services

Comment: Agreed - no guarantee the sound keeps playing when the activity is not visible - your activity can be destroyed when the system is under load and short of memory.   Also, your app may be running when other application's activities are visible -   This is how a music player would be expected to work, but is it what you expect?

Comment: @shahbaz pothiawala  did you find  the correct sollution? I did like this. I wrote a bound service. Handling Starting and stoping of the service in application class. In each activity I am starting service in onstart() and stoping in onPause.

Comment: create media player in service... work done!

Comment: Thats great. In my case, my download service stops (similar to your media playback) when I close my app. How did you manage to get your service to still work even the app is killed?

Answer (score 9):

Create a separate class for handling several conditions

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;

public class MusicManager {
    static final int MUSIC_PREVIOUS = -1;
    private static final String TAG = "MusicManager";
    static MediaPlayer mp;
    private static int currentMusic = -1;
    private static int previousMusic = -1;


    public static void start(Context context, int music) {
        start(context, music, false);
    }

    public static void start(Context context, int music, boolean force) {
        if (!force && currentMusic > -1) {
// already playing some music and not forced to change
            return;
        }

        if (music == MUSIC_PREVIOUS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Using previous music [" + previousMusic + "]");
            music = previousMusic;
        }
        if (currentMusic == music) {
// already playing this music
            return;
        }
        if (currentMusic != -1) {
            previousMusic = currentMusic;
            Log.d(TAG, "Previous music was [" + previousMusic + "]");
// playing some other music, pause it and change
            pause();
        }
        currentMusic = music;
        Log.d(TAG, "Current music is now [" + currentMusic + "]");
        if (mp != null) {
            if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.start();
            }
        } else {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.backGroundMusic); //Ur BackGround Music
        }

        if (mp == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "player was not created successfully");
        } else {
            try {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void pause() {
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
            }
        }

// previousMusic should always be something valid
        if (currentMusic != -1) {
            {
                previousMusic = currentMusic;
                Log.d(TAG, "Previous music was [" + previousMusic + "]");
            }
            currentMusic = -1;
            Log.d(TAG, "Current music is now [" + currentMusic + "]");
        }
    }

    public static void release() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Releasing media players");
        try {
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
                mp.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        if (currentMusic != -1) {
            previousMusic = currentMusic;
            Log.d(TAG, "Previous music was [" + previousMusic + "]");
        }
        currentMusic = -1;
        Log.d(TAG, "Current music is now [" + currentMusic + "]");
    }
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity` define a global boolean variable and set it to `true` before setContentView(....) in `onCreate()` i.e

```
    boolean continueBGMusic;
    ....
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        continueBGMusic=true;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .....
    }
```

Then update `onPause()` as

```
    public void onPause()
        {
            super.onPause();
            if(!continueBGMusic)
                MusicManager.pause();
    }
```

and `onResume()` as

```
    public void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();

                continueBGMusic=false;
                MusicManager.start(this,R.raw.backGroundMusic);
    }
```

Update all ur three activities with the boolean variable and the two methods.

Comment: @Bhava: I've set up everything just like you posted above, however the music isn't playing. Did I miss anything along the way?

Answer (score 4):

If you have not very much activities,
You can manage this task by adding boolean flags in activities, where you want music to be played.
When you stop one Activity these flags will show you, whether other Activities need your MediaPlayer

So in your main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static MediaPlayer introPlayer;
    static boolean sActive;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

    // starting the player if it is not playing
        if (!introPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            introPlayer.start();
            introPlayer.setLooping(true);
        }

        // true when activity is active
        sActive = true;
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        sActive = false;
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        // before stoping mediaplayer checking whether it is not used by other          activities

        if (introPlayer.isPlaying()
                && !(Activity2.sActive || Activity3.sActive)) {
            introPlayer.pause();
        }

        super.onStop();

    }
}
```

Other activities:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    static boolean sActive;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        sActive = false;

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        // pausing the player in case of exiting from the app
        if (MainActivity.introPlayer.isPlaying() && !(MainActivity.sActive || Activity3.sActive)) {
            MainActivity.introPlayer.pause();
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        sActive = true;

        if (!MainActivity.introPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            MainActivity.introPlayer.start();
            MainActivity.introPlayer.setLooping(true);
        }

        super.onResume();
        }
}
```

And

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity {

    static boolean sActive;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        sActive = false;

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        // pausing the player in case of exiting from the app
        if (MainActivity.introPlayer.isPlaying() && !(MainActivity.sActive || Activity2.sActive)) {
            MainActivity.introPlayer.pause();
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        sActive = true;

        if (!MainActivity.introPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            MainActivity.introPlayer.start();
            MainActivity.introPlayer.setLooping(true);
        }

        super.onResume();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
        music.stop();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

else if you have any separate button action for closing the app, there to u can call as music.stop();

Comment: ok, so the user goes from first activity to another(the sound continues) but if he goes back to first activity from second the sound will stop, isn't?

Comment: write the above in ur first activty alone and in places where the app gets closed without going to first activity....

Comment: what if the user ends the application by pressing home button or the application is interrupted by a phone call or something?

Comment: Huge assumption here that the user navigates out of the app with the back button, and that the application has only one activity.  Neither is a given.

Comment: @Marko - i really accept what you said, but i cant think on all logic what shahbaz needs, but this is the way to stop a music.....

Comment: @shahbazpothiawala - you try calling music.stop() in OnPause and onDestriy methods too

Comment: Siva, if at all i wanted a temporary solution like one of yours, I wouldn't have asked this question in stack overflow. That is an obvious but incorrect answer. Had thought of all such temporary solutions before posting the question here. All I want is a proper solution which works in any condition.

Comment: when there is a phone call, onPause and onStop are called, onDestroy may be called but you can't rely on it. so try the solutions in these parts....

Answer (score 0):

**You have to simply call the music.stop() whenever you leave the application.** You can do this in `onStop()` method of your launcher activity if your app consists only one activity.

I would suggest you to use **SoundPool** if you want to efficiently play the sounds. Using it you can play lots of concurrent sounds. I also made a demo project of SoundPool. You can find it [here](http://getandroidinmystyle.blogspot.in/)

When you use MediaPlayer object you'll have to manage all the things by own your own. I also used the same in my first game. But now for my new game I'm using SoundPool. It was added in API 1 n still rocks.

Comment: Neither my application contains only one activity nor do I have many sounds to play concurrently. Just one background music to continue throughtout the app that has three different activities!

Comment: Okay so just stop it when you leave the application.

Answer (score 0):

i did this by following way

initialize

```
    MediaPlayer player;
    Music music;
```

in OnCreate

```
    music = new Music();
    music.execute("abc");
```

when you want to stop music, usually in onDestroy method

```
        music.cancel(true);
        if(player.isPlaying()){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        }
```

create music class

```
  public class Music extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        if(running)
        {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bg_music1); 
        player.setVolume(100,100); 
        player.setLooping(true); 
        player.start(); 
        }
        else
        {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCancelled();
        running = false;
    }
}
```

another way is to use service

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) and track the starting and stopping of activities to know when your app is "stopped". This would be when a call comes in to onActivityStopped and not followed by a call to onActivityStarted within a small timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

To start playing music you will need to figure out when our application starts. We can do that by extending [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. Application object is instantiated before any activity and is preserved until our app is terminated by the Android OS.
That makes it ideal to control playback only within this object. When we create new class that extends Application we must register it into our manifest.

We have determined when our application is created but what about stopping the music when our application goes from foreground to background? Android offers no out-of-the-box method for determining that. To solve that problem I followed this [very good article](http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/12/determining-if-your-android-application.html) and part of the solution code was from there.

Code for Application:

```
package com.example.stackmusic; 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class PlayMusicApp extends Application {


private MediaPlayer music;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyLifecycleHandler());

    music = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.some_music);
}

/**
 * All activities created in our application will call these methods on their respective
 * lifecycle methods.
 */
class MyLifecycleHandler implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private int resumed;
    private int stopped;

    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        // this is the first activity created
        if(resumed == 0) {
            music.start();
        }
        ++resumed;
    }

    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    }

    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        ++stopped;
        android.util.Log.w("test", "application is being backgrounded: " + (resumed == stopped));
        // we are stopping the last visible activity
        if(resumed == stopped) {
            music.stop();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Registration in manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".PlayMusicApp"
```

You don't want to play music in the UI thread. Ideally create a service for playing music in background thread instead of managing media player in Application object.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the song, you can do music.stop() on Destroy. means music stops when your app closed or killed

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    music.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Very Simple is when you want your MediaPlayer volume off, try to set up with setVolume(int leftVolume, int RightVolume)

So whenever you want to stop your MediaPlayer's Volume off. use

```
music.setVolume(0,0);
```

Even you can pause with  stop your MediaPlayer with `music.pause();`

And Stop mediaplayer with `music.stop();`

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to go into your Android settings > Apps > (name of your music player), then tap "Force Stop". Confirm the operation, and the music should stop. It may not work with all music players, but it's worth a shot.

If you must have code, have you tried assigning `music.pause()`? This command stops the music.

Comment: why question in answer?

Comment: I'm not really questioning; I'm just proposing a solution. If it seems too much like one, I can rephrase it by request.