# How to stop mediaPlayer when app goes to background?

Tags: java, android

How do I stop MediaPlayer only when whole app goes to background.
If I call MediaPlayer.Stop() in onPause() it will be stopped in other activity.

Comment: you can call in onDestroy()

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871288/android-media-player-plays-in-the-background-but-doesnt-stop-when-app-killed

Comment: Detect When app is going to background and stop the Mediaplayer.
To detect app foreground and background state check this Link https://medium.com/@arturogdg/background-and-foreground-events-with-android-architecture-components-233fdd9fa855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner) solves this problem beautifully. It is a special kind of [LifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner) that is a composite of all of your Activities. **It provides lifecycle for the whole application process.**

You can use it to react on your app coming to the foreground or going to the background with very little code.

Checkout more details in this medium post [React to foreground and background events with ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://proandroiddev.com/react-to-app-foreground-and-background-events-with-processlifecycleowner-96278e5816fa)

Check demo at [AppLifecycleDemo](http://github.com/jshvarts/AppLifecycleDemo)

Comment: @SpicyIsland Welcome friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to follow along these lines: [Stop MediaPlayer service when app goes in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838000/stop-mediaplayer-service-when-app-goes-in-background). Switching to call it onDestroy() is another option.